# How to add a new row in Dataview from Existing dataview in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Dataview and I want to add only few records from that Dataview to another new Dataview.

Please suggest how can i do that.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean exactly and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll show you some code.

Suppose that you have 2 datagridviews (`dtgv` and `dtgv2`) with 2 columns and many rows.

```
' Create a condition 
Dim condition As Boolean = False
' Loop through all rows in the first dtgv
For i As Integer = 0 To dtgv.Rows.Count - 1
    ' If your condition is true
    If condition = True Then
        ' Create a row with dtgv's values
        Dim row As Object() = New Object() {dtgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, _
                                            dtgv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value}
        ' Add this row to the second dtgv (dtgv2)
        dtgv2.Rows.Add(row)
    End If
Next
```